# React component not linking to HTML div

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React and wanted to inject the nav bar I created in HTML, into my original document. However the React component isnt linking to the div in the HTML, I'm not really too sure as to what is wrong to be honest!

```js
 var NavBar = React.Component({
  render () {
    return (
    <div className="nav">
       <div className="bottom-nav">
           <div className="container-fluid">
            <a href="home.html" className="logo-link"><img className="logo" src="assets/images/alt-logo-2.png" alt="Native Creative"></img></a>
            <input className="menu-btn" type="checkbox" id="menu-btn" />
            <label className="menu-icon" for="menu-btn"><span className="navicon"></span></label>
            <ul className="menu">
             <li className="item"><a href="collection.html">Collection</a></li>
             <li className="item"><a href="inspiration.html">Inspiration</a></li>
             <li className="item"><a href="http://nativecreative.bigcartel.com/" target="_blank">Shop</a></li>
             <li className="item"><a href="contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
           </div>
        </div>
   </div>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <NavBar />,
  document.getElementById('navbar')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>


<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
  <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <!-- - - - - - - - NAVIGATION START - - - - - - - -->

<div id="navbar"></div>
<script src="javascript/navbar.js"></script>

  <!-- - - - - - - - NAVIGATION END - - - - - - - -->

</body>
```

Comment: `class NavBar extends React.Component { //... }`

Comment: What error do you get in your console?

Comment: SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<' @Swanand

Answer (score 1):

Use `class NavBar` instead `var NavBar =`

Here is the example:

```js
class NavBar extends React.Component {


  render() {
    return (       
        <div className="nav">
           <div className="bottom-nav">
              <div className="container-fluid">
                 <a href="home.html" className="logo-link"><img className="logo" src="assets/images/alt-logo-2.png" alt="Native Creative"></img></a>
                 <input className="menu-btn" type="checkbox" id="menu-btn" />
                 <label className="menu-icon" for="menu-btn"><span className="navicon"></span></label>
                 <ul className="menu">
                    <li className="item"><a href="collection.html">Collection</a></li>
                    <li className="item"><a href="inspiration.html">Inspiration</a></li>
                    <li className="item"><a href="http://nativecreative.bigcartel.com/" target="_blank">Shop</a></li>
                    <li className="item"><a href="contact">Contact</a></li>
                 </ul>
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
}


ReactDOM.render( <
  NavBar / > ,
  document.getElementById('navbar')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id='navbar'></div>
```

Comment: it works on the code snippet online but not on my local file, any ideas?

Comment: Dependencies missing. Try to create new react app with https://reactjs.org/blog/2016/07/22/create-apps-with-no-configuration.html create-react-app nameofapp. Need to install node and -g create-react-app first.

Answer (score 0):

Correct syntax #1

```
 var NavBar = React.createClass({ // ...})
```

Correct syntax #2

```
 class Navbar extends React.Component { // ...}
```

Make sure you use a transpiler (e.g. Babel) or the JSX will not be interpreted correctly.